# How to write a backslash escape behind \?

Tags: php

How to write a backslash escape behind \ ?
`$newer =  "e:\www\test\".$str.".html";`

By the way, how to post a php code? Forgive I am a newer.

Comment: If you have a question about how to use Stack Overflow, please post it at http://meta.stackoverflow.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a double backslash, e.g. `"e:\\www\\test"`.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.

Answer (score 0):

In you backlash escape question, you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415683/in-php-do-i-need-to-escape-backslashes), same question as yours

In posting a php code, you can read this tutorials.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/feedbackphp.shtml