# PHP escape in String

Tags: php

I am calling a function which is passed a string like below

```
$templateProcessor->saveAs('C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\templates\doc1.docx');
```

Problem is, I need it to be more like

```
$templateProcessor->saveAs('C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\templates\' . $this->fileName . '.docx');
```

If I do this however, my string breaks and I think it is due to the backslashes in the string.

How can I resolve this?

p.s. I actually would prefer to do something like this

```
$templateProcessor->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../templates/doc1.docx');
```

but it didnt seem to like me using ../../ because I need to step out of the current working directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To escape the backslashes just place an additional backslash before them.

```
$fileName = 'file';
$path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\portal\\templates\\' . $fileName . '.docx';
print $path;
```

To make `dirname` work, you might just need an additional slash:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../templates/doc1.docx';
print $path;
```

Answer (score 3):

only last backslash need to be escaped

```
$templateProcessor->saveAs('C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\templates\\' . $this->fileName . '.docx');
```

because with single quotes are recognized only `\\` and `\'`, single backslash is interpreted as character - so you were escaping single quote

look at this answer
[In PHP do i need to escape backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415683/in-php-do-i-need-to-escape-backslashes)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to build paths is probably to use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant  since it adapts to the OS you are using :

```
$path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('C:','xampp','htdocs','portal','templates',$this.filename.'.docx'));
$templateProcessor->saveAs($path);
```

Then you should also put your path in a config file in case you need to edit it some day.

In PHP 5.6 you can make a variadic function.

```
<?php
/**
* Builds a file path with the appropriate directory separator.
* @param string $segments,... unlimited number of path segments
* @return string Path
*/
function file_build_path(...$segments) {
    return join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $segments);
}

file_build_path("home", "alice", "Documents", "example.txt");
?>
```

In earlier PHP versions you can use func_get_args.

```
<?php
function file_build_path() {
    return join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, func_get_args($segments));
}

file_build_path("home", "alice", "Documents", "example.txt");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change,

```
$templateProcessor->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../templates/doc1.docx');
```

to

```
$templateProcessor->saveAs($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/templates/doc1.docx');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can siomply avoid the escaping by using a double slash

```
$templateProcessor->
saveAs('C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\templates\\' . $this->fileName . '.docx');
```