# How to add backslash next to php magic constants?

Tags: php, file-exists

I'm trying to check if file exists or not. I tried simple http URL for the task but `file_exists()` does not support (my php version is `5.5.12` and `allow url fopen` is activated ).

So i tried in different way and its working, see below

```
if(file_exists(__DIR__.'\email_template.php')) {
    echo  'Template is available.';
}
```

Problem is that i'm adding template name dynamically and i need backslash between `__DIR__` and `$temp_name` but i can't concatenate properly. I tried below

```
$__DIR = __DIR__.'\';
$__DIR = __DIR__.'"\"';
$__DIR =  __DIR__."\";
```

But no one is working, its return syntac error. So can anyone guide me how can i fix the issue i would like to appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$__DIR = __DIR__.'\\';
```

Backshlash is special char in PHP (and other languages as well), that is used for noting that chars after them should be interpreted in special way - and is named "escape char".
You do not want this to happen, so You should escape backshlas... By using one more backshlash. ;)

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415683/in-php-do-i-need-to-escape-backslashes).

Comment: Added explanation. If this is answer for Your question - mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the pre-defined constant [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php).

```
$__DIR = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

This way your code is more portable between operating systems, which may or may not be of concern to you.